# Name of button won't change with setState

Tags: reactjs

I am begining learning React.
I am following along to a tutorial video, and when I press the button, the name should change from Juju to Julie.  But when I press the button, the name doesn't change.
I keep comparing the code to the code I see in the video and it seems identical.
Please bear with me, I am trying to learn React and I am at the very beginning, I just cant figure out why the name won't change.
Here is my App.js code:

```
import { Component } from "react";

import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    name: "Juju",
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>Hi {this.state.name}</p>
        <button
          onclick={() => {
            this.setState({ name: "Julie" });
          }}
        >
          Change name
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You have a typo. just change ```onclick``` to ```onClick```

Comment: Thanks, I was using auto-completion so I didn't catch that error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you have used should be onClick. Please try the followed code.

```
    <button onClick={() => {this.setState({ name: "Julie" }) }} >
      Change name
    </button>
```